# How to control Windows from Android Keyboard?

Tags: java, android, sockets, keylistener, keyevent

I created the mobile app on client side for Android successfully.

Then Server side, that is windows server code also created. I can able to type all the letters numbers and all.

My problem is using shift key and "@" key. I need "@" into my project. When I press the "@" crashes the connection and says...

Invalid key code
    at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
    at pcHotkey.keyboardServer$Capitalizer.run

Now, how should I type "@" with my app. Then I press shift key it was passing correctly and it was not stopping the pressed state.

My code goes here,

```css
 1st class:
    aMap.put("Shift", KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        aMap.put("At", KeyEvent.VK_AT);
    try{
        robo =  new Robot();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9898);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }        
  

     2nd class :

        public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
            log("New connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                // Send a welcome message to the client.
                out.println("Hello, you are client #" + clientNumber + ".");
                out.println("Enter a line with only a period to quit\n");

               while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(input);
                    if(input.equals("Caps")){
                     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
                                   ;
                    }


                    else if(input.equals("At"))
                    {
                     log("Log Value : "+ input);
                     //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, true);
                     
                     robo.keyPress(aMap.get("At"));
                     //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, true);
                    }
                    else
                    robo.keyPress(aMap.get(input));

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
                }
                log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
            }
```

Comment: At least "@" symbol insertion is enough for now. How to fix this? Can anyone help for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did by passing the keycode of "SHIFT" and "2". Problem got fixed now.